# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to connect my Flutter application with firebase authentication and I am getting this error when importing it.
[image]

I have also added the dependency in pubspec.yaml file.

[image]

Please guide

Comment: Did you run flutter pub get?

Comment: Yes, I did that too, and it is showing that the dependency is already there.